# Google Oauth2 login using requests in hackerrank

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-authentication

I am new to requests library and [requests-oauthlib](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I am trying to scrape all my submissions on hackerrank and have generated my client id and client key using GCP.

But confused about what to use as the **redirect_url**, **resource_owner_key** and **secret** and how to use requests library with the session and cookies.

Kindly guide me with some resources so I can solve this.